# Progress Bar Seek Correct Target Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap progress bar for an audio player. It looks something like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

My seek function works correctly if you try to seek forward (past the current value of the progress bar).

The code I'm using for the seek function is the following:

```
seek: function(e) {
  if (!audio.readyState) return false;
  var xpos = e.offsetX / e.target.offsetWidth;
  audio.currentTime = (xpos * audio.duration);
}
```

However, if you try to seek backwards (click a value less than the current value), the value will be incorrect because the e.target.offsetWidth is not the entire progress bar, but only the blue portion of the progress bar.

For instance, if the progress bar value is at 50%, and you click/seek to 25%, the value will not change. This is because the when you click at 25% of the whole progress bar, you are actually clicking 50% of the "progress-bar" class div (the blue part).

```
<div class="progress ng-isolate-scope" max="1" value="(player.currentTime / player.duration)" ng-click="player.seek($event)">
  <div class="progress-bar" ng-class="type &amp;&amp; 'progress-bar-' + type" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0.18599028015468233" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" ng-style="{width: percent + '%'}" aria-valuetext="19%" ng-transclude="" style="width: 18.6%;"></div>
</div>
```

I need this:

```
var xpos = e.offsetX / e.target.offsetWidth
```

to become something like this:

```
var xpos = e.offsetX / e.target.parent().offsetWidth
```

But that does not work. How do I select the parent element of the target in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you add the event listener? Both part and full element should receive the event, for example:

```js
document.querySelector('.bar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('bar', e);
});
document.querySelector('.part').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('part', e);
});
```

```css
.bar, .part {
    height: 50px;
}

.bar {
    width: 200px;
    background: gray;
}

.part {
    width: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='bar'><div class='part'></div></div>
```

Clicking on the blue part in the example triggers both event listeners, so you'll only need to listen for events on the `.bar` (full) element.